# How to translate content of a sharepoint page (.aspx)

Tags: sharepoint-online, variations, machine-translation

I created a variation label on my site collection. I added a page in the page library in english, I was hoping that the content is translated on another label but the page is still in english. Anyone knows how to translate a content on the page?